# How to calculate each day's profit in Trading View Strategy Tester

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I want to set a daily profit target, lets say of $500. Once the net profit during that trading day is at or above $500, I want strategy tester to stop taking trades until the next trading day.I could use the strategy.netprofit function but that wouldn't work over the span of multiple days.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

dailyNetProfitLimit = input(500)

canTrade(dailyNetProfitLimit)=>
    var bool canTrade = false
    tD = time("D")
    var float dailyProfitStart = na
    if tD!=tD[1] or na(dailyProfitStart) // new day or start
        dailyProfitStart := strategy.netprofit
        canTrade := true
    if strategy.netprofit - dailyProfitStart >= dailyNetProfitLimit
        canTrade := false
    canTrade

canTrade = canTrade(dailyNetProfitLimit)

// debug plot
plot(strategy.netprofit, color = canTrade?color.green:color.red)


longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition and canTrade)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition and canTrade)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```