# Limit intraday trading if daily loss exceeds a set limit - pine

Tags: pine-script, trading

I am writing a TradingView Strategy and want to limit intraday trading to a set daily profit or loss.

I have the limit working on daily profit but I can not get the daily loss bit working.

I followed Andrey D's post here to get the daily profit working
[How to calculate each day's profit in Trading View Strategy Tester](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71903695/how-to-calculate-each-days-profit-in-trading-view-strategy-tester)

this is the code that is working for me

//**** Daily Net Profit Limit*****
var useNetProfit = input.bool(true, title = "Limit to Daily Net Profit", confirm=false, group="Positions")
var useNetLoss = input.bool(false, title = "Limit to Daily Net Loss", confirm=false, group="Positions")
dailyNetProfitLimit = input(title="Daily Profit Limit", defval=40, group="Positions")
dailyNetLossLimit = input(title="Daily Loss Limit", defval=40, group="Positions")

```
canTrade(dailyNetProfitLimit)=>
    var bool canTrade = false
    tD = time("D")
    var float dailyProfitStart = na
    if tD!=tD[1] or na(dailyProfitStart) and useNetProfit // new day or start
        dailyProfitStart := strategy.netprofit
        canTrade := true
    if strategy.netprofit - dailyProfitStart >= dailyNetProfitLimit and useNetProfit
       canTrade := false

    canTrade
canTrade = canTrade(dailyNetProfitLimit)
```

//**** End Daily Net Profit Limit ********************

then use the "cantrade" value in my strategy entry conditions
if canTrade
strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long)

This all works and I can toggle the feature on and off in the settings.

I tried creating a second "function" called cantrade2 for daily losses but it doesnt work

```
canTrade2(dailyNetLossLimit)=>
    var bool canTrade2 = false
    tD = time("D")
    var float dailyLossStart = na
    if tD!=tD[1] or na(dailyLossStart) and useNetLoss // new day or start
        dailyLossStart := strategy.netprofit
        canTrade2 := true
    if strategy.netprofit <= dailyLossStart - dailyNetLossLimit and useNetLoss
        canTrade2 := false
    canTrade2

canTrade2 = canTrade2(dailyNetLossLimit)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strategy.risk.max_intraday_loss()` function to set the maximum lost.

> The maximum loss value allowed during a day. It is specified either in money (base currency), or in percentage of maximum intraday equity (0 -100).

It take few parameters:

> **value (simple int/float)** A required parameter. The maximum loss value. It is specified either in money (base currency), or in percentage of maximum intraday equity. For % of equity the range of allowed values is from 0 to 100.
>
> **type (simple string)** A required parameter. The type of the value. Please specify one of the following values: strategy.percent_of_equity
> or strategy.cash. Note: if equity drops down to zero or to a negative
> and the strategy.percent_of_equity is specified, all pending orders
> are cancelled, all open positions are closed and no new orders can be
> placed for good.
>
> **alert_message (simple string)** An optional parameter which replaces the {{strategy.order.alert_message}} placeholder when it is used in
> the "Create Alert" dialog box's "Message" field.

Here's the example from documentation:

```
// Input for maximum intraday loss %. 
lossPct = input.float(10)

// Set maximum intraday loss to our lossPct input
strategy.risk.max_intraday_loss(lossPct, strategy.percent_of_equity)
```

Comment: Hi, yes thanks I know I can use that line in the code, but its global in the code.
I would like the ability to toggle it on and off in the settings like the daily profit function.

I cant understand why the Daily Profit function code works but the Daily Loss function code doesnt?